# Getting current foreground app's PID is not working when switch to another user in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, process, daemon

I've developed daemon which checks every 10 seconds current application's PID. Daemon live all the time after OS X startup even after switching between users. 
The problem is that when I switch into another user the functionality below always return PID as "0".
Here is a code:

```
pid_t pid = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication] processIdentifier];
```

How to fix the following problem?

EDIT: Also tried to get using Carbon:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0L, 0L };
OSStatus err = GetFrontProcess(&psn);

CFStringRef processName = NULL;
err = CopyProcessName(&psn, &processName);
NSLog(@"PID: %s", CFStringGetCStringPtr(processName, NULL));

CFRelease(processName);
```

Comment: in which context it is running? if its in root context then the code above will look for the `frontmostApplication` of root user not your `loggedIn` user.

Comment: In `XCode` you will not be able to test this as `XCode` elevates its permissions to root.

Comment: But it works for user where I installed daemon for the first time. Why it doesn't work when I switch into another? Daemon is launched under root.

Comment: You're trying to use a high-level framework that's only aware of a single execution context. See [Technical Q&A QA1133: Determining console user login status](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1133/_index.html) for this specific issue, but pay close attention to the caveats it mentions. Also, be sure to read [Technical Note TN2083: Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html) that it links to.

Comment: I read that document and seems there is no solution how to do on low level or "switch" tracking another login session...

Comment: Also tried to get foreground app name using Carbon. When I switch into another user it displays PID of previous user foreground PID. (code I used see above)

Comment: You should use an agent (which is per-user and per-session) rather than a daemon to track this. Each agent can track the frontmost app in its session. If necessary, the agents can coordinate with a daemon, which can track the active session.